# HTML form opens new tab instead of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I've written a simple form which receives input as text from user, then validates it using jscript function, and if valid submits the form into an iframe.

The form is targeted into the iframe and the onsubmit attribute contains "return func()" value (assume func() is a Boolean function returns true/false depending on the validation process).
Now the problem is that once onsubmit is set to "return func()" it submits the form to a new tab whereas onsubmit is set to "func()" (i.e doesn't perform the validation) it submits the form to the iframe as desired.

Assume func() only validates the input and return true/false and doesn't modify any of the document fields.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: are you SURE it is targeted into the iframe? A typo could cause it to do a new tab instead because the names wouldn't match then so the browser thinks needs to make a new window.

Comment: I am sure because when the onsubmit attribute is not set to "return func()" it submits it to the iframe

Comment: post the code. What are we supposed to do? Take your word for what the code looks like and does? Post the code.

Comment: wait, onsubmit falls form.submit again? That'd submit it twice... once by the automatic submit (unless you return false) and once by the script. I'd just use the target attribute to set the target and do a traditional onsubmit = return validate thing.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
I accidentally redirected the iFrame from within the jscrip function to an invalid path.